# Where does log(x) / x take maximum value?

Tags: calculus

If the base of the logarithm is `e`, one can say `log(x)/x` takes maximum at `e`.

If the base of the logarithm is `10`, one can say `log(x)/x` takes maximum at `10`.

But `log10(x)/x` is nothing but `(loge(e)/loge(10))/x`.

The two functions are just a constant multiple (`1/loge(10)`) of each other. Shouldn't they have the same maxima?

Comment: You are right, unless we do something grotesque and take a base in the interval $(0,1)$. The maximum is at the same **place**. Of course it does not have the same **value**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but doesn't my last statement contradict everything?

Comment: Also, can someone please help me with tags here? I can't seem to add any relevant tags. None among "minima", "extrema", "decreasing" exist.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your second sentence, which is wrong. They all are max at $x=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence is correct, whatever base $b$ we take (as long as $b\gt 1)$, the function $\frac{\log_b x}{x}$ reaches a maximum at $x=e$. The reasoning that led to that conclusion is clearly stated.

The assertion in the second sentence that $\frac{\log_{10} x}{x}$ reaches a maximum at $x=10$ is not true.